# Consulta con Like para busqueda de caracteres que no esten dentro de la A a la Z

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me encuentro haciendo una búsqueda en mi base de datos. La búsqueda consiste en encontrar filas con caracteres que no pertenecen al alfabeto (de la `'A'` a la `'Z'`) por ejemplo `'Þ'`, `'%'` o un Ampersand '`&`'.

En la imagen adjunta, muestro la consulta y el resultado que me arroja; en el resultado no veo el símbolo que estoy buscando en el LIKE. No entiendo por que pasa esto, ¿alguien tiene alguna idea?

[image: Consulta like con resultado incongruente]

Comment: nada que ver, pero que tiene que ver el group by ahi?

Comment: @gbianchi, lo utiliza en lugar de un `distinct`, y funciona

Comment: Puede que funcione, pero su funcionalidad es otra. El distinct busca filas totalmente distintas.. el group by agrupa por un campo que tengan el mismo valor, y devuelve una funcion de agregacion de la misma. y para filtrar en un group, se usa having. Es un error utilizarlo de esta forma. Mas alla de eso, quiero suponer que filtrando por algo que realmente no este, realmente no trae nada no?

Comment: Pues, ya elimine el group by , solo queria agrupar por numero de parte, y para ocasionar menos conflicto entre la comunidad ya no lo estoy utilizando, el problema que tengo presente, es la busqueda en base a caracteres "extraños como $%^#$#! el simbolo de euro ", no entiendo por que si busco el caracter  Þ me muestra un resultado como este "LTH8007Z" donde no se presenta el caracter--> Þ

Answer (score 1):

Se debe a la tabla de equivalencias de la colección de cotejo (`collates`) **`Latin1_General*`** del SQL Server (excepto la binaria). Probablemente otras listas de cotejo tengan el mismo comportamiento. Desconozco la que estás utilizando en el servidor/tabla/sesión.

No me atrevo a definir aún esto como un *bug*, ya que desconozco si dicho carácter tendrá alguna pronunciación en algún lugar del mundo donde se utilice este juego de caracteres, aunque ciertamente no en el mundo de habla hispana/inglesa.

He realizado varias pruebas con un SQL Server 2014 (12.0.5000) y SQL Server 2017 (14.0.1000), obteniendo los mismos resultados.

Lo que he podido observar, es que SQL detecta que el carácter de marras como equivalente a la secuencia de caracteres `'TH'`. Por tanto te retorna todas las filas que tengan dicha secuencia.

Puedes comprobarlo fácilmente con la siguiente consultas:

```
with
no_partemp as (
          select 'HT-DS100TH' collate latin1_General_100_ci_ai no_parte
union all select 'MAXVS940TH'
union all select 'MAXVS950TH'
union all select 'MAXVS990TH'
union all select 'MAXZS530TH'
union all select 'MAXZS720TH'
union all select 'MM39TH/XAP'
union all select 'RCDS30TH'
union all select 'RCDS50TH'
union all select 'THD-750'
union all select 'T000000'  --Este registro se excluye
union all select 'TH00000'
)
select   ascii('Þ') ascii_de_busqueda
       , char(ascii('Þ')) caracter_de_busqueda
       , charindex('Þ', no_parte) posicion_encontrada
       , no_parte
       , substring(no_parte, charindex('Þ', no_parte), 1) caracter_coincidencia
       , ascii(substring(no_parte, charindex('Þ', no_parte), 1)) ascii_coincidencia
  from no_partemp
 where no_parte like '%Þ%';
```

Que devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
ascii_de_busqueda caracter_de_busqueda posicion_encontrada no_parte   caracter_coincidencia ascii_coincidencia
----------------- -------------------- ------------------- ---------- --------------------- ------------------
222               Þ                    9                   HT-DS100TH T                     84
222               Þ                    9                   MAXVS940TH T                     84
222               Þ                    9                   MAXVS950TH T                     84
222               Þ                    9                   MAXVS990TH T                     84
222               Þ                    9                   MAXZS530TH T                     84
222               Þ                    9                   MAXZS720TH T                     84
222               Þ                    5                   MM39TH/XAP T                     84
222               Þ                    7                   RCDS30TH   T                     84
222               Þ                    7                   RCDS50TH   T                     84
222               Þ                    1                   THD-750    T                     84
222               Þ                    1                   TH00000    T                     84

(11 row(s) affected)
```

La consulta que sigue, sería *idéntica* a la anterior, excepto que en esta utilizo el `collate latin1_General_100_bin`, con el cual realiza la comparación exacta y no devuelve ningún resultado (ni devuelve mayúsculas como coincidencia de minúsculas, etc.)

```
with
no_partemp as (
          select 'HT-DS100TH' collate latin1_General_100_bin no_parte
union all select 'MAXVS940TH'
union all select 'MAXVS950TH'
union all select 'MAXVS990TH'
union all select 'MAXZS530TH'
union all select 'MAXZS720TH'
union all select 'MM39TH/XAP'
union all select 'RCDS30TH'
union all select 'RCDS50TH'
union all select 'THD-750'
union all select 'T000000'
union all select 'TH00000'
)
select   ascii('Þ') ascii_de_busqueda
       , char(ascii('Þ')) caracter_de_busqueda
       , charindex('Þ', no_parte) posicion_encontrada
       , no_parte
       , substring(no_parte, charindex('Þ', no_parte), 1) caracter_coincidencia
       , ascii(substring(no_parte, charindex('Þ', no_parte), 1)) ascii_coincidencia
  from no_partemp
 where no_parte like '%Þ%';
```

Resultado:

```
ascii_de_busqueda caracter_de_busqueda posicion_encontrada no_parte   caracter_coincidencia ascii_coincidencia
----------------- -------------------- ------------------- ---------- --------------------- ------------------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Es interesante observar que incluso con el tipo de dato NVarchar se observa el mismo comportamiento:

```
with
no_partemp as (
          select N'HT-DS100TH' no_parte
union all select 'MAXVS940TH'
union all select 'MAXVS950TH'
union all select 'MAXVS990TH'
union all select 'MAXZS530TH'
union all select 'MAXZS720TH'
union all select 'MM39TH/XAP'
union all select 'RCDS30TH'
union all select 'RCDS50TH'
union all select 'THD-750'
union all select 'T000000'
union all select 'TH00000'
)
select   ascii('Þ') ascii_de_busqueda
       , char(ascii('Þ')) caracter_de_busqueda
       , charindex('Þ', no_parte) posicion_encontrada
       , no_parte
       , substring(no_parte, charindex('Þ', no_parte), 1) caracter_coincidencia
       , ascii(substring(no_parte, charindex('Þ', no_parte), 1)) ascii_coincidencia
  from no_partemp
 where no_parte like N'%Þ%';
```

Esta devuelve los mismos resultados de la primera consulta, que ya no repito para no abusar del espacio.